# How to write JPA query for below SQL query

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am writing JPA query for below SQL query. I am new for this. Could you please help me..!!

Thank you in advance.

```
select distinct 
sdsmbr.MCID,sdsmbr.HCID,sdsmbr.SOR_CD,ehubsdsmbr1_.MBR_SQNC_NBR,ehubsdsmbr1_.NEW_MBR_CD, ehubsdsmbr1_.SBSCRBR_ID,ehubsdscvr3_.CVRG_EFCTV_DT,ehubsdscvr3_.CVRG_TRMNTN_DT,
ehubsdscvr3_.CVRG_STTS_CD,cntrct.CNTRCT_TYPE_CD
from
EHUB_MBR_SDS.EHUB_SDS_MBR sdsmbr
inner join
EHUB_MBR_SDS.EHUB_SDS_MBR_CNTRCT ehubsdsmbr1_
on sdsmbr.EHUB_MBR_ID=ehubsdsmbr1_.EHUB_MBR_ID
inner join
EHUB_MBR_SDS.EHUB_SDS_CNTRCT cntrct
on ehubsdsmbr1_.CNTRCT_ID=cntrct.CNTRCT_ID
inner join
EHUB_MBR_SDS.EHUB_SDS_CVRG ehubsdscvr3_
on ehubsdsmbr1_.EHUB_MBR_CNTRCT_ID=ehubsdscvr3_.EHUB_MBR_CNTRCT_ID
where sdsmbr.SOR_CD = 'test'
and ( ehubsdsmbr1_.MBR_SQNC_NBR ='test' or ehubsdsmbr1_.NEW_MBR_CD ='test')
and (sdsmbr.HCID ='test' or ehubsdsmbr1_.SBSCRBR_ID ='test');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by my own. Please find below and may be this will helpful to write your queries. If you have better solution please suggest.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT " +
            "sdsmbr.mcid,sdsmbr.hcid,sdsmbr.sorCd,ehubsdsmbr1_.mbrSqncNbr,ehubsdsmbr1_.newmbrCd,ehubsdscvr3_.cvrgEfctvDt,ehubsdscvr3_.cvrgTrmntnDt, " +
            "ehubsdscvr3_.cvrgSttsCd,cntrct.cntrctTypeCd, ehubsdsmbr1_.sbscrbrId " +
            "From EhubSdsMbr sdsmbr " +
            "JOIN " +
            "sdsmbr.ehubSdsMbrCntrcts ehubsdsmbr1_ " +
            "JOIN " +
            "ehubsdsmbr1_.ehubSdsCntrct cntrct " +
            "JOIN " +
            "ehubsdsmbr1_.ehubSdsCvrgs ehubsdscvr3_ " +
            "where sdsmbr.sorCd = ?1 " +
            "and ( ehubsdsmbr1_.mbrSqncNbr = ?2 or ehubsdsmbr1_.newmbrCd = ?3) " +
            "and ( sdsmbr.hcid = ?4 or ehubsdsmbr1_.sbscrbrId = ?5)")
```